# Post prefix Unary operator strange behaviour

Tags: java

Following is my code.

```
public class ShortCkt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 0;
        boolean t = true;
        boolean f = false, b;
        b = (t || ((i++) == 0));// why the value of i does not gets increased?
        b = (f || ((i += 2) > 0));
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

**Output** : **2**

Why the output is 2 and not 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `||` operator operates as a short-circuit if the first operand is `true`.

Since the first operand **is** `true` (`t == true`), the second condition (that increments `i`) is not evaluated.

In the second case, the first operand `f` is `false`, hence the second operand is evaluated and `i` gets incremented by `2`, ending with value `0 + 2 == 2`.

This differs from the `&&` operator, which requires both operands to be evaluated.

The bitwise operators `&` and `|` also evaluate both operands when used in boolean conditions.

**Summary**

- `b = (t || ((i++) == 0)); // b = true OR... whatever, just true`
- `b = (t | ((i++) == 0)); // b = true bitwise or 0 == 0 == true (postfix increment, so i gets incremented after evaluation --> true`
- `b = (t | ((++i) == 0)); // b = true bitwise or 0 == 0 == true (prefix increment, so i gets incremented before evaluation --> false`
- `b = (t && ((++i) == 0)); // b = true AND 1 == 0 == false (prefix increment, so i gets incremented before evaluation --> false`
- `b = (t & ((++i) == 0)); // b = true bitwise and 1 == 0 == false (prefix increment, so i gets incremented before evaluation --> false`

Comment: how did you get such a deep knowledge?

Comment: @rns haha actually by mistyping a few operators across a whole class and seriously messing up an android app prototype once, right before latest built was demoed to management. **Now** I can laugh of it.

Answer (score 3):

`((i++) == 0))` is never evaluated, since `t` is `true` and `||` is a short circuited OR operator, so the second (right) operand is only evaluated if the first (left) operand is `false`.

In `(f || ((i += 2) > 0))`, both operands are evaluated, since `f` is false. Therefore `i` is incremented from 0 to 2.